# Allow list subscribers to update their email addresses?

Tags: civimail, mailing

We have a list of people who work at many different companies with company email addresses. When someone moves to a new job at a new company their email address changes. How can we make it simple for someone who changes jobs to come to a CiviCRM Webform and change the email address we have for them? This would relieve our tiny staff of a major burden!

Answer (score 5):

Creating such a profile is fairly straightforward.  The (potentially) hard part is for CiviCRM to know who the person is.  You have three options:

- If your users can log into your site, then the site will know who they are.
- If you can trust your users to enter their data correctly, you can give them a blank form to fill out and configure your [Unsupervised Dedupe Rule](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#dedupe-rules) to identify the record that needs updating.
- You can create an email linking users to the profile using a URL with a [checksum token](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/).  These can be a bit confusing to add to your emails for non-technical folk, in which case you may want to install the [Fancy Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/fancy-tokens) extension, which gives a nicer user experience.

As for the form itself, you can use a [profile](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/), or if you need something fancier you can use Webform with CiviCRM integration (if you use Drupal or Backdrop) or Caldera Forms CiviCRM (if WordPress).

If you haven't created a form like this before, and you aren't a documentation learner, you can find videos on YouTube covering CiviCRM profiles.

It often helps to include first and last name as read-only fields, it helps folks understand that the system knows who they are.

Comment: I realize that this is a very high-level answer - but in fairness, it's a very high-level question!  If you get stuck, it may be helpful to open a follow-up question.